# How to fake an action<> with FakeItEasy

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, action, fakeiteasy

I'm working with the FakeItEasy library to create fakes for my unit tests.

I have a `ClassUnderTest` on which I want to test the method `MethodToTest(Data dataObject)`. This method is calling a method of an interface which I want to fake:

```
public interface IFoo
{
  void Execute(Action<IDataAccess> action);
}

public class ClassUnderTest
{
  private IFoo _foo;

  public ClassUnderTest(IFoo foo)
  {
    _foo = foo;
  }

  public void MethodToTest(Data dataObject)
  {
    _foo.Execute(dataAccess => dataAccess.Update(dataObject));
  }
}

public interface IDataAccess
{
  void Update(Data data);
}

public class Data
{
  public int Property { get; set; }
}
```

In my unit tests I want to check if the test method calls the interface correctly (with the correct property value):

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
  [TestMethod]
  public void TestMethod1()
  {
    var foo = A.Fake<IFoo>(x => x.Strict());
    A.CallTo(() => foo.Execute(dataAccess => dataAccess.Update(A<Data>.That.Matches(d => d.Property == 20))));      

    var cut = new ClassUnderTest(foo);

    cut.MethodToTest(new Data { Property = 20 });      
  }
}
```

But something is configured wrong in this test. I get the exception:

> Test method TestProject1.UnitTest1.TestMethod1 threw exception: 
>   FakeItEasy.ExpectationException: Call to non configured method "Execute" of strict fake.

Does somebody have an idea of how I have to configure the `CallTo()` statement correctly?

Comment: Easily, I'd say ...?  :)  (ok, ok, I'll give this a read over ... )

Comment: Are you certain the code you've presented is even compiling? `ClassUnderTest` does not have a parameterless constructor (I'm assuming it's a class - but that is also missing from the code), but you seem to use one...

Comment: @decPL: you are right, I corrected the sample above. the foo-fake is passed in the costructor.

Comment: and `dataAccess` is...?

Comment: @decPL: this is the issue I have. calling the Execute method on the fake I have to define that the foo fake offers a IDataAccess which the MethodToTest can use for calling the .Update(dataObject) method

Comment: I think @decPL is on to something - that's how I'd check that `Execute` was called, but I also think that something else is going on, aside from all the compilation errors (which persist - there's no "class" by `ClassUnderTest`, if nothing else). FakeItEasy complains that `foo` is a "Strict fake", which is not the default. Is there additional code you're not showing? Or maybe an `IFakeConfigurator` somewhere?

Comment: @BlairConrad: thanks for your help. I revised my sample. Hope now is more understandable. You're right, normaly I also do not use Strict fakes but the .MustHaveHappened() to demand the assert. But i got the same error with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The updated example really helps, @rhe1980.

First some notes about the test you supplied:

1. the `A.CallTo` method doesn't do anything - it's not setting up behaviour (with a `.Invokes` or a `.Returns` or even a `.DoesNothing`) or verifying that the method has been called (for example with `.MustHaveHappened`).
2. Comparing `Action`s appears to be tough. I did find some advice over at [Compare Delegates Action<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701041/compare-delegates-actiont), but if it were me, I'd take a slightly different tack.

Instead of attempting to compare the `Action` delegate to a reference model, I figured I could emulate this by capturing the action supplied to `Execute` and then running it on an `IDataAccess` and see *what the action does*. Fortunately, we have FakeItEasy to help with that!

I had success with this test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    // Arrange
    var foo = A.Fake<IFoo>(x => x.Strict());

    var fakeDataAccess = A.Fake<IDataAccess>();

    A.CallTo(() => foo.Execute(A<Action<IDataAccess>>.Ignored))
                    .Invokes((Action<IDataAccess> action)=>action(fakeDataAccess));

    var cut = new ClassUnderTest(foo);

    // Act
    cut.MethodToTest(new Data { Property = 20 });

    // Assert
    A.CallTo(() => fakeDataAccess.Update(A<Data>.That.Matches(d => d.Property == 20)))
        .MustHaveHappened();
}
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your intentions correctly, you need to use something as follows:

```
A.CallTo(() => foo.Execute(A<Action<IDataAccess>>.Ignored).MustHaveHappened();
```

Comment: I agree, and ideally after running `MethodToTest`. I think there are other problems with the sample code, though. See my comment on the question.